# VueJS + VueRouter: Conditionally Disabling A Route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I wonder how to disable a route in VueRouter conditionally, so that it can't be accessed anymore!

I tried to redirect with `this.$router.replace('/')` but the URL did show the route that I wanted to skip.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**

this is my VUEX-Store: Have a look at `router.replace('/')`

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    users: [ ],
    friendships: [ ],
    userID: null
  },
  mutations: {
    signUp(state, payload) {
      auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password).then((user) => {
        if (user !== null) {
          state.userID = user.uid
          router.replace('/')
        }
        else {
          state.userID = null
        }
      })
    },
    signIn(state, payload) {
      auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password).then((user) => {
        if (user !== null) {
          state.userID = user.uid
          router.replace('/')
        }
        else {
          state.userID = null
        }
      })
    },
    signOut(state) {
      auth.signOut()
      state.userID = null
      router.replace('/signin')
    },
    authenticate(state) {
      auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user !== null) {
          state.userID = user.uid
          router.replace('/')
        }
        else {
          state.userID = null
        }
      })
    }
  },
  actions: {
    signUp({ commit }) {
      commit('signUp')
    },
    signIn({ commit }) {
      commit('signIn')
    },
    signOut({ commit }) {
      commit('signOut')
    },
    authenticate({ commit }) {
      commit('authenticate')
    },
    redirect({ commit }) {
      commit('redirect')
    }
  }
})
```

and here is my component:

```
<template>
  <div id="you">
    <h1>you</h1>
    <p>You are on your secret page!</p>
    <p>{{ $store.state.userID }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'you',
    beforeCreate() {
      if (this.$store.state.userID === null) {
        this.$router.replace('/signin')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add [a meta feild](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/meta.html) to that route you want to conditionally disable it like this:

```
export const routes = [
  {path: '/', component: foo},
  {path: '/bar', component: bar, meta:{conditionalRoute:true}}
];
```

And use `router.beforeEach` in your main.js :

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => { 
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.conditionalRoute)) { 
        // this route requires condition to be accessed
        // if not, redirect to home page. 
        if (!checkCondition) { 
            //check codition is false
            next({ path: '/'}) 
        } else { 
            //check codition is true
            next() 
        } 
    } else { 
        next() // make sure to always call next()! 
    } 
})
```

Or else use `beforeRouteEnter()` [navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html) locally on that route's component

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next){
    next(vm => { 
        // access to component instance via `vm` 
        if(checkCondition){
            next();
        }else{
            next('/');
        }
    })
}
```

In your signin component

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next){
    next(vm => { 
        // access to component instance via `vm` 
        if(vm.$store.state.userUID !== null){
            next('/');
        }else{
            next();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: thank you for the insights, but my question would rather be: how can I prevent the URL from taking in a path name of a route that i don't want to enter ! Thank you.

Comment: @timomue what do you mean by URL not taking a path name of a route that i don't want to enter?

Comment: during redirect the url shows a path (for just a second) that it shouldn't show, vue loads a component, that I don't want it to load, vue should skip rendering that component.

Comment: @timomue where are you using `this.$router.replace('/')`

Comment: when I refresh the page the whole site tries to navigate to "signin" (for the fraction of a second) and THEN performs the redirect...

Comment: @timomue add beforeRouteEnter in your sigin component and check the vuex state `userUID` , if it is not null i.e user is signedin redirect to home page , this will not show the signin component because beforeEoiteEnter is called befor the component is rendered, have a look at my answer edit

Comment: hey thanks, it is better now, except: my userID needs time to take its value from the database (firebase) ... how to tackle this problem?

Comment: @timomue you can save the vuex state(UID) in a cookie  using vuex-persisted state. Have a look at my answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44126493/i-want-to-use-window-localstorage-in-vuex-in-nuxt-js/44138549#44138549)

Answer (score -1):

In your route, you can use [navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) to check if the route matches the route you want to disable and then `return` instead of executing `next()`

```
router.beforeEach(to, from, next) {
  if (to.path === "yourRoute") {
    return;
  }
}
```