# Unusual redirects

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I create an application with Vue.js, vue-router and firebase. In the `main.js` file I put this code:

```
created() {
    firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        authDomain: "xxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
        storageBucket: "",
    })
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if(user) {
           this.$store.dispatch('autoSignIn', user)
        }
    })
}
```

This is a Vue-Store:

```
state: {
    user: null
},
mutations: {
    setUser(state, payload) {
        state.user = payload
    }
},
actions: {
    autoSignIn({commit}, payload) {
        commit('setUser', {
            id: payload.uid
        })
    }
}
```

In the vue-router, I made sure that before proceeding to the root directory, it checked whether the user was authorized. If not, redirect it to the login page. And in the login page, it checks whether the user is authorized. If not then redirects to the root directory. So, I'm logged in and I'm in the root directory. I reload the page and I immediately redirect to the login page and immediately redirected to the root directory and nothing else happens. All this happens in 1 second, and looks ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` is asynchronous. So by the time we are able to access the `user` the route guard is being executed . That's the reason you are being redirected to the login page.

By that time the async call has finished we have access to the `user`. Since you are checking for `user` in the login page and now that the `user` is available you are kicked back to root route.

Firebase by default stores a token in `localStorage` under the key `'firebase:authUser'` for keeping the [auth state persisted](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence) .

So you can check whether this key is present in `localStorage` in your route guard

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => { 
  //check local storage
  let loccalStorageKeys = Object.keys(window.localStorage);
  const firebaseAuthUser = loccalStorageKeys.filter(item => item.startsWith('firebase:authUser'))[0];

  if(firebaseAuthUser){
    next();
  }else{{
    next('/login');
  }}
})
```

Since the check is synchronous , it should prevent the jumping redirects.

Or the alternative would be to persist the vuex state corresponding to the `user` using a vuex plugin called `vuex-persistedstate`. Then check for the `user` state for guarding the routes. Then when the user logs out clear the `user` state. Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44126493/i-want-to-use-window-localstorage-in-vuex-in-nuxt-js/44138549#44138549) regarding vuex-persisted state.

## **NOTE:**

As of [firebase v4.12.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#4.12.0) the auth state persistance(for LOCAL persistance) is moved from local storage to indexedDB.

As this is an internal implementation of firebase and may change in future, so relying on checking whether `firebase:authUser` is present in local storage to confirm user's login status is not a good idea.

So it would be better to persist the user data as mentioned in the alternative method above  and use that to check the user is logged in or not

Comment: WOW! Thank you! I accidentally deleted the firebase key . I tried to sign in and create an account but the firebase keys are not created. But I can sign in.